# How to show post by user in one page in PHP & MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have database structure like this:

[image]

`table name: tblpost` and I want to show all post by user like show post by multiple user in only page name: **allpost.php**

---

And I want to get result like this:

[image]

So how to show data like that? Many thanks for all your answer.

Comment: Please, can you edit the question showing an your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use PDO.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * from tblposts where post_by=:post_by");
$stmt->bindParam(':post_by',$user);
$stmt->execute();
//Fetches the posts for the certain user you want
$posts = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

MySQLi:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * from tblposts where post_by=?");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$user);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result(); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo $row['post_date'];
}
```

Comment: Can you give me MySQLi Procedural code cause I don't understand PDO code?